# MYSQL: Select a row for a given filter and the maximum value of key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (tUsuariosLog) which contains the history of updated information for a given user. So If I want to read the current information of a given user then I need to row with the greatest key value in key column (the key column has auto_increment).

Here is the query that I use to get it.

```
SELECT * FROM tUsuariosLog WHERE cUid = '15' AND cKeyid = (SELECT MAX(cKeyid) FROM tUsuariosLog WHERE cUid = '15')
```

It seems that this is an overcomplicated way of achieving what I want (it does work though).

My question is if there is a better way to get what I want that a query within a query.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `order by` and `limit`?

```
SELECT ul.*
FROM tUsuariosLog ul
WHERE cUid = 15 
ORDER BY cKeyid DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I am guessing that `cUid` is a number, not a string, so I removed the single quotes.

For performance, you want an index on `tUsuariosLog(cUid, cKeyid)`.

Comment: That is actually a great Idea!! Love it! Thanks!